# Wordpress site suddenly not showing some DOM elements but mobile is fine

Tags: html, css, wordpress, dom, webkit

So today I discovered that my website's homepage https://olgupsikoloji.com is missing body elements. It is a WP site running on AWS Ubuntu and LiteSpeed with LSCache and Memcached.

The issue is: Some DOM elements right after title bar appear to be hidden, but they are there, just not visible. You can click on them or view hidden images by dragging them.

Here's what I've done: Yesterday, I updated some of the texts in other pages (which are fine) and nothing on homepage.

Here's what I tried to troubleshoot:

- Bypassed Cloudflare
- Cleared LSCache
- Disabled all plugins
- Updated Wordpress
- Updated the theme
- Tested on multiple browsers and devices
- Tested on Safari for iOS (no issues)
- Tested on Chrome for Android (no issues)
- Page Builder seems okay, no open tags or any broken element.

As far as I can tell, it's a rendering issue on Webkit browsers for desktop (?)

I appreciate all the help, it's been driving me crazy.

Comment: which elements specifically are missing?

Comment: for example there is <div class="post-thumbnail"> which is not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your styles.css on line `10041` you have a class with `opacity` set to 0

```
.page-has-animation .page-content .tm-animation {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

and its missing the class to fade it in. (`.fade-in.animate`)

Comment: I believe that initiates page animation. When I set individual elements opacity to 1 nothing shows up.

Comment: As suspected, this was the issue. The reason that it never occurred to us to even check the style.css is the fact that we never made any changes to it. Thanks for the help.